# Can't create new MatchCollection -- no constructors defined

Tags: c#

So, maybe I'm tired, but why can't I create a new `MatchCollection`?

I have a method that returns a `MatchCollection` by calling `regex.Matches`:

```
public static MatchCollection GetStringsWithinBiggerString(string sourceString)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\$\(.+?\)");

    return regex.Matches(sourceString);
}
```

What I wanted to do was return an empty collection if the parameter was null:

```
public static MatchCollection GetStringsWithinBiggerString(string sourceString)
{
    if (sourceString == null)
    {
        return new MatchCollection();
    }

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\$\(.+?\)");

    return regex.Matches(sourceString);
}
```

But that won't compile because of this line:

```
return new MatchCollection();
```

The error:

> The type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' has no
>   constructors defined.

How can a type have no constructors defined? I thought a default constructor would be created if no constructor was explicitly defined. Is it not possible to create a new instance of `MatchCollection` for my method to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can a type have no constructors defined?

It can't. But it can hide all of its constructors by making them non-public - i.e. private, internal, or protected. Moreover, once a constructor is defined, the default constructor becomes inaccessible. Other classes in the same namespace can access internal constructors, but the classes external to the namespace would not be able to instantiate a class directly.

P.S. If you would like to create an empty match collection, you can always make an expression that matches something, and pass it something else:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"foo");
var empty = regex.Matches("bar"); // "foo" does not match "bar"
```

Comment: Actually if you define a constructor with arguments, you cannot use the default constructor anymore unless you explicitely declare it.

Comment: +1. Ahhhh... wasn't thinking about non-public constructors. Oops. Thanks. So I can't return an empty `MatchCollection` unless I do some work-around like BrunoLM mentioned in his answer?

Answer (score 6):

Very appropriate use of the [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern!

Implement like this:

```
public static MatchCollection GetStringsWithinBiggerString(string sourceString)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\$\(.+?\)");

    return regex.Matches(sourceString ?? String.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a workaround:

If the `sourceString` is `null` set it to `""` and continue the execution.